# connect node app running in windows to redis running in wsl

Tags: node.js, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i have setup wsl in my windows server machine and started the redis service there.
from the windows command prompt i can use `wsl redis-cli` and run the redis commands.
but my node application is not able to detect the redis inside wsl. i am using [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) in my node project.

is there any third party module i need to add to able to connect, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56200672/can-i-use-redis-installed-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-with-a-python-app-in-wi) showed to add it in python.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455770/11810933) answers your question.  Different software, but same principal.

Answer (score 0):

the wsl's redis port was readily available.
`const client = redis.createClient();` just kept the createClient() config blank and it connected.